How to close jetcd election client without errors
All client configurations work without any problems.
Election class in the Jetcd library has the following observe method,
void observe(ByteSequence electionName, Listener listener);

With this method you can know who the leader is.
But when I close etcd client, if I am observing, it throws exception.
  public void disconnect() {
    this.leaseKeepAliveClient.close();
    this.lease.revoke(this.leaseId);
    this.client.close();
  }


io.etcd.jetcd.common.exception.EtcdException: Channel shutdownNow invoked
    at io.etcd.jetcd.common.exception.EtcdExceptionFactory.newEtcdException(EtcdExceptionFactory.java:35)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.common.exception.EtcdExceptionFactory.fromStatus(EtcdExceptionFactory.java:83)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.common.exception.EtcdExceptionFactory.toEtcdException(EtcdExceptionFactory.java:79)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.common.exception.EtcdExceptionFactory.toEtcdException(EtcdExceptionFactory.java:74)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.impl.ElectionImpl.lambda$observe$6(ElectionImpl.java:144)
    at io.vertx.grpc.stub.StreamObserverReadStream.onError(StreamObserverReadStream.java:44)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:481)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:564).
    ....
    ....
    ....

Is there a sequence for closing?

import io.etcd.jetcd.Client;
import io.etcd.jetcd.election.Election;
import io.etcd.jetcd.election.ElectionClient;

public class JetcdElectionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = Client.builder().endpoints("http://localhost:2379").build();
        Election election = client.getElectionClient();
        
        try {
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        
            try {
                election.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing election client: " + e.getMessage());
            }
       
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
Always close the election client in a finally block .


Thank you for your reply,
However, this exception is not related to your reply, Addition, Client close method is already calling election close method. ConnectionManager throw exception while closing , I think something on gRPC codes is causing this.
